# What is the best book to learn : Free products with amalgamation.

Tags: book-recommendation, free-product

I'm studying groups with Abstact Algebra Grillet, in the free product part, there's a page about amalgamation with two propositions with no proofs, I will be glad if you can recommand a book where this subject is treated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: A book that doesn't call it "free product with amalgamation"...the sooner you start calling it a colimit the better.

Comment: Thanks, I will search for it !!

Comment: It seems to be hard to find one that is suitable. Clearly there is a need. It is surprising because Category Theory is usually considered part of Algebra. It seems that most category theory books avoid the coproduct of groups, and most algebra books that do the coproduct of groups call it the free product. Shortest path I can see: learn about coproducts, colimits (and products and limits) in basic category theory, then understand how the free product is a coproduct and the free product with amalgamation is a colimit.